# How to set display text filter in django-admin list_display?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a field that contains markdown. When I display it in my templates I can just put in `{{activity.activity_notes|markdown}}` to get it to format correctly. When it shows up in the Django admin, though, it is unfiltered and doesn't look nice.

I wrote a custom function to return compiled markdown, but when outputting it in Django admin it shows the literal html, tags and all. Is there a way I can set the output filter for a field in the Django admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `get_markedown_activity_notes` method to your model and use it in admin `list_display`
The method will look like this

```
from django.contrib.markup.templatetags import markdown

class Activity(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_markedown_activity_notes(self):
        return markdown(self.activity_notes)

#in admin.py

class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('id','get_markedown_activity_notes',)
```

For more use cases see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: And don't forget to put `get_markedown_activity_notes.allow_tags = True` somewhere in your models.py otherwise Django will escape the HTML output.